# Mejor o mas eficiente practica en php

Tags: php

Tengo dos templates: header.php y footer.php.
Y algunas otras paginas: index.php, menu.php, page_1.php, page_2.php

¿Cuál es la mejor (o más eficiente) opción?

**OPCION UNO**

*Index.php:*

> require 'header.php'
>
> require $page; //Se asigna en menu.php; $page = page_1.php
>
> require 'footer.php'

*page_1.php:*

> /* ... Contenido de page_1.php ... */

**OPCION DOS**

En cada pagina, incluir los templates header.php and footer.php.

*page_1.php:*

> require 'header.php'
>
> /* ... Contenido de page_1.php ... */
>
> require 'footer.php'

*page_2.php:*

> require 'header.php'
>
> /* ... Contenido de page_2.php ... */
>
> require 'footer.php'

Comment: He agregado medidas de tiempo en las que verás que es tan despreciable el tiempo de diferencia comparado con la carga del propio script, que sea cual sea tu decisión no afectará de manera drástica al rendimiento de tu web.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de cómo quieras implementarlo y la utilidad que le vas a dar a la primera opción (en particular). La diferencia de tiempo entre una y otra solución es despreciable comparada con el tiempo de carga del propio script, por lo que usar una u otra no afectará drásticamente (o de manera apreciable) al rendimiento.

He tratado de medir el tiempo de 500 ejecuciones de una forma y otra e incluso sin hacer nada el PHP y éste es el resultado (no concluyente):

```
$ time ( i=500; while [ $i -gt 0 ] ; do php pr1.php ; i=$((i-1)) ; done )
real    0m9.151s
user    0m6.104s
sys 0m2.440s

$ time ( i=500; while [ $i -gt 0 ] ; do php pr2.php ; i=$((i-1)) ; done )
real    0m9.248s
user    0m6.260s
sys 0m2.288s

$ time ( i=500; while [ $i -gt 0 ] ; do php pr3.php ; i=$((i-1)) ; done )
real    0m9.028s
user    0m6.080s
sys 0m2.284s
```

El ejemplo `pr1.php` contiene un archivo PHP vacío (sólo con `<?php`) y `pr2.php` hace un `require` de dos archivos adicionales, `inc1.php` e `inc2.php`, también vacíos.

Como puedes ver la diferencia entre no hacer nada e incluir dos archivos es de apenas el 1%.

El ejemplo `pr3.php` carga 8 archivos de `inc1.php` a `inc8.php` y, si me dejara llevar por los resultados, habría que deducir que cuantos más archivos requieres más rápido se ejecuta el PHP :)

Lo dicho, el tiempo de trabajo con archivos es despreciable con la sobrecarga de la ejecución del propio script PHP.

---

Todos los que usan MVC (como es mi caso) estarán de acuerdo en que la primera tiene más posibilidades porque podrías concentrar el esfuerzo del enrutamiento en un único archivo (un único punto de entrada).

Conforme crece un proyecto es más difícil mantener los archivos PHP, su seguridad, etc. Deberías pensarte empezar a usar un framework que te solucione todo el tema de MVC y lo que rodea al tratamiento de peticiones HTTP.

Tienes para elegir muchas opciones:

- Laravel
- Symfony
- Slim
- etc

Es asumible la pérdida de rendimiento (y no tan grande como muchos piensan) respecto a la ganancia en cuanto a organización y estructura del proyecto, seguridad, legibilidad, etc.